# Folding Custom Regions in Pycharm not working after certain indentation levels

Tags: pycharm

It seems Folding Custom Regions in Pycharm is not working after certain indentation levels.

This one doens't work:

```
def test_a():
    def function():
        for g in group:
            if g[0] is not "BLA":
                task(g)  # <editor-fold desc="# Log...">
                logger.debug('Log this')  # Log  #  </editor-fold>
```

This one works:

```
def test_b():
    def function():
        for g in group:
            task(g)  # <editor-fold desc="# Log...">
            logger.debug('Log this')  # Log  #  </editor-fold>
```

The VisualStudio style (#region, #endregion) doesn't seem to work in this scenario either. This issue only seems to happen when the line comments are placed at the end of the lines.

Thanks ins advance for your help!

Comment: I have encountered the same problem, has a bug report been filed to Jetbrains yet?

Answer (score 0):

My workaround for this issue with VisualStudio style (#region, #endregion) looks like this:

```
# region test
def test_a():
    def function():
        for g in group:
            if g[0] is not "BLA":
                task(g)
                logger.debug('Log this')
pass
# endregion
```

In python code I just add `pass` at the end of the region. If anyone finds better solution, please answer.

**UPD**: it is still an open issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-17017

**UPD**: Hooray! Fixed in 2017.3!

Comment: Yes, actually I stumbled upon this workaround by mistake and have been using it ever since. I am going to accept this answer in the meantime.